# C-extension in Python: Conver wchar string to Python Value

Tags: python, python-c-extension

In C-extension of Python, I can use `Py_BuildValue()` to Conver char string to Python Value like this: `Py_BuildValue("s", str)`. But, if the string is wchar array, the `Py_BuildValue("s", str)` can not be used.

I think I can use PyUnicode like this:

```
PyObject* pb=PyUnicode_FromUnicode( (const Py_UNICODE*)(str), wcslen(str) );
PyObject *val = Py_BuildValue("o", pb);
```

But, it does not work. How can I conver wchar string to Python Value?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to combine `PyUnicode_FromUnicode` and `Py_BuildValue`.

The following `pb` is already a Python unicode object.

```
PyObject* pb=PyUnicode_FromUnicode( (const Py_UNICODE*)(str), wcslen(str) );
```

Using `Py_BuildValue` to process it is redundant, but it's harmless.
I think your problem is caused by the incorrect format `o`. It should be `O`.

You can also use `Py_BuildValue` to convert a null-terminated buffer of Unicode (UCS-2 or UCS-4) data to a Python Unicode object.
For example:

```
const wchar_t *w = L"Hello world!";
PyObject* pb = Py_BuildValue("u", w);
```

More